# Laravel whereIn get duplicates also

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm a front-end developer that has been asked to do some Laravel adjustments so please bear with me.

This is the code I'm trying to modify -

```
$location = Location::where('id', $id)->with('plants')->get();
$plantId = PlantLocation::where('location_id', $id)->get('plant_id');
$plants = Plant::whereIn('id', $plantId)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
```

The way it works is on the form is that there are 3 dropdowns - Participant, Site(location), Plants. Each dropdown's information is tied to the previous dropdown using JavaScript to populate each one.

The DB has 4 tables - Participants(users), Locations, Plants, Plant Locations. There are relationships between them.

On the form first you select the Participant, the DB is queried and you get a list of Site tied to the Participant. Then you choose a Site and get a list of Plants tied to the Site.

[Form Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrR2E.png)

So far everything works well with no issues. Here's what I need to update.

In the Plants Location table say I have 3 unique Plants tied to a Site - Rose, Tulip, Orchid, everything works fine and I see [Rose, Tulip, Orchid] in the Plants dropdown.

But if I have the >1 (greater than 1) of the same plant tied to a site (example Rose, Tulip, Rose), I see [Rose, Tulip]. What I want is [Rose, Tulip, Rose] as my output.

From what I understand, the whereIn statements only shows 1 instance and not duplicates. I have tried every piece of code and solution that I could find on the internet to show the duplicates with no luck. At first I thought the JavaScript was messing with it but I output the ajax request I only see [Rose, Tulip].

Can someone point me in the right direction please? Thank you!

Comment: Please share the models and the schema if possible. It sounds like you want to show all plants at a location regardless of dups.

Comment: Have you tried just defining a `$plants = collect()`, looping over your `PlantLocation` records and pushing their associated `$plantLocation->plant` to said Collection? You're correct that `whereIn('id', [1, 2])` will only ever return at most 2 records (assume 1 is Rose, 2 is Tulip). Even if you did `whereIn('id', [1, 2, 1])`, it would still only return up to 2 rows. You'll most likely need to construct the array/Collection manually, or using a combination of `->pluck('plants')` and `$plants->merge($morePlants)`, etc.

Comment: Why don't use relation in `PlantLocation::where('location_id', $id)->get('plant_id');` like `PlantLocation::where('location_id', $id)->with('plants')->get()->pluck('plants');` this will return  collection of plants for specific location id. you don't need to whereIn statement anymore.